# Where can I find a 12.10 DVD image?

Tags: 12.10, dvd, cd, alternative

While I'm open to buying a DVD from the shop, I'd rather download a DVD image, but I can't find it on the Download page (only the CD images and the option to buying a DVD).

I have slow internet where I live, I always relied on the Alternative CD.  But now with it gone for 12.10, so I looked for alternatives (DVD Image).

So where can I find a DVD image, or is the only way to get one is to buy a DVD from the shop?

Answer (score 4):

The "CD Image" is the DVD image. It is now too big to fit in a CD. You can either burn it in a DVD or put it in an USB stick using  the software described in ubuntu.com.

Download the 12.10 desktop DVD image from: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

For 12.10, The traditional Live CD image, alternate downloader image and DVD image has gone. Now there is only one type of image for the Desktop.

It is named as Desktop image and is a bit bigger than the former CD images and smaller than the former DVD images.

You can look at the various images for 12.10 from this link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/

Comment: So there is no other alternative to the Alternative CD. And I have to download all the packages now

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for the alternate cd for the .deb files there, I'm sorry, You can't. You have to download the packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the cd/dvd images of ubuntu releases [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/).
Everything of Ubuntu can be found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/).
Hope this will help you.